# A way to convert a DataTable to a gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I am working on an asp.net/C# project and I need to know if it is possible to convert a DataTable to a gridview in C#.

Comment: You can use your `DataTable` with [`.DataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd385422%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of Gridview. Don't forget to set [`AuthoGenerateColumns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to `true`

Comment: No, these are two completely separate domains. You can however [bind a DataTable to a GridView](http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/4325-bind-datatable-to-gridview.aspx)

Comment: ok so I tried it out in my code and it seems like it is working so far. I will continue coding and if there is a problem I will comment again.

Answer (score 1):

```
string Database = "Name Of Database";
SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SqlServerName; Initial Catalog=" + Database + ";Integrated Security=True");
SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TableName", Con);

DataTable Table = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Cmd);
Adapter.Fill(Table);

Grid.DataSource = Table;
Grid.DataBind();
```